# Views with common properties in ViewFlipper

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to set shared properties for all views in `ViewFlipper`? F.e., if all items in VF are buttons with the same width and height, can I somehow set it in VF so I don't have to code width and height for each button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using styles. For more information see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can set a Theme for your Activity or if you want to, your whole application. 
So e.g.:

```
<style name="Theme.DeviceDefault.Light" parent="Theme.Holo" > 
   <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonText</item>
</style>
```